# Does the logarithmic nature of global warming invalidate climate change claims?

Tags: climate-change, climatology

**NOTE**
It is rather unfortunate that I initially omitted the crucial part of the article I linked below (because the wording was stilted and confusing), and I was rather imprecise in my own claims.  What I am specifically asking about is **the two degree increase in overall earth temperature** cited by most climate change experts which, if the claims of the article I cited were true, *will never be reached.*

I'm not asking about severe weather events, nor am I (or the article) claiming that global warming does not occur.

---

According to [The effectiveness of CO<sub>2</sub> as a greenhouse gas becomes ever more marginal with greater concentration](https://wattsupwiththat.com/2013/05/08/the-effectiveness-of-co2-as-a-greenhouse-gas-becomes-ever-more-marginal-with-greater-concentration/):

> According to well understood physical parameters, **the effectiveness of
>   CO<sub>2</sub> as a greenhouse gas diminishes logarithmically with increasing
>   concentration and from the current level of ~390 ppmv**, (parts per
>   million by volume). Accordingly only ~5% of the effectiveness of CO<sub>2</sub>
>   as a greenhouse gas remains beyond the current level.
>
> This inconvenient fact is well understood in the climate science
>   community. It can be accurately modeled using the Modtran program
>   maintained and supported at the University of Chicago.
>
> The logarithmic diminution of the effect of CO<sub>2</sub> is probably the reason
>   why there was no runaway greenhouse warming from CO<sub>2</sub> in earlier eons
>   when CO<sub>2</sub> levels were known to be at levels of several thousands ppmv.
>
> Remarkably, IPCC Published reports , (TAR3), do actually acknowledge
>   that the effective temperature increase caused by growing
>   concentrations of CO<sub>2</sub> in the atmosphere radically diminishes with
>   increasing concentrations. This information is in their report. It is
>   well disguised for any lay reader, (Chapter 6. Radiative Forcing of
>   Climate Change: section 6.3.4 Total Well-Mixed Greenhouse Gas Forcing
>   Estimate).
>
> Although the IPCC tacitly acknowledges that this crucial diminution
>   effect with increasing concentrations effect exists, it certainly does
>   not go out of its way to emphasise it. Like the Medieval Warm Period,
>   that they attempted to eliminate with the Hockey Stick graph in 2001,
>   the panel knows that wide public knowledge of the diminution effect
>   with increasing CO<sub>2</sub> concentration would be utterly detrimental to
>   their primary message.
>
> From the present concentration of atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> at approaching 400 ppmv, only ~5% of the effectiveness of CO<sub>2</sub> as a Greenhouse Gas remains.  This can only give rise to a maximum of a further of ~+0.21°C. Thereafter beyond 1000+ ppmv the effect of increasing levels of CO<sub>2</sub> can only ever be absolutely minimal even if CO<sub>2</sub> concentrations were to increase indefinitely.

If this is true, then global warming is a self-regulating phenomenon; that is, it will, in effect, level off.  And it will do so before reaching the levels that the climate change advocates say will cause catastrophic problems.

Is this true?  And if it is, why doesn't it completely invalidate the claims of climate change advocates?

Comment: In addition to Venus, I would offer the Permian-Triassic extinction as a disproof by example.

Comment: I suspect the "debate" about climate change may be over: UN ambassador Nikki Haley has said that Trump now believes in climate change.

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  The current CO2 levels cause a **lot** of warming.  Earth would average around the freezing point without it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The claim that *"... the effectiveness of CO2 as a greenhouse gas diminishes logarithmically with increasing concentration and from the current level of ~390 ppmv, ..."* and that *"inconvenient fact"* is *"well disguised for any lay reader"* is one of the more ridiculous climate skeptic claims I've seen.  The main metric used by climate scientists to describe the effect of carbon dioxide is called *["climate sensitivity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_sensitivity)*.  Equilibrium climate sensitivity is the amount of warming we expect to see resulting from a ***doubling*** of atmospheric CO2.  This directly tells you (provided you understand logarithms) that there is a logarithmic relationship between carbon dioxide concentrations.  If ECS is 2°C per doubling that means if we raise CO2 from the pre-industrial equilibrium concentration (i.e. up to 560ppm from 280ppm) then we would expect to see a 2°C temperature rise once the climate system had fully re-equilibriated.  However to get the next 2°C rise, you would need to double the atmospheric CO2 again (i.e. up to 1120 ppm) and to get a third 2°C increase you would need to double it again, up to 2240ppm.

Note that log<sub>2</sub>(280) = 8.1293, log<sub>2</sub>(560) = 9.1293, log<sub>2</sub>(1120) = 10.1293 and log<sub>2</sub>(2240) = 11.1293, so if we have y=c*log<sub>2</sub>(x), each time we double x, y increased by c, which is why expressing climate sensitivity in °C per doubling is just saying that the relationship is logarithmic in a way that ought to be clear even to someone who doesn't know what a logarithm is.  The constant c in this equation is ECS, if you use a log to a different base (e.g. ln or log<sub>10</sub>) then the numeric value of c will be different, but the relationship is the same, it is just easier to explain in terms of log<sub>2</sub>.  This is hardly rocket science!

Clearly, there is a "diminishing returns" effect here, but (i) far from hiding it, the climatologists are explicitly pointing it out in a form more easily understood even than logarithms (ii) to get a 2°C rise, you would only need to double CO2 levels from the pre-industrial level of 280ppm, and we have raised it to 400ppm already, so this is far from impossible, given that estimates of ECS are around 1.5-4.5°C per doubling.

> "there is high confidence that ECS is extremely unlikely less than
>   1°C and medium confidence that the ECS is likely between 1.5°C and
>   4.5°C and very unlikely greater than 6°C." [IPCC AR5 WG1, page 924](http://www.climatechange2013.org/images/report/WG1AR5_Chapter10_FINAL.pdf)

Do a [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=climate%20sensitivity) for "climate sensitivity", or look for it in the index of the IPCC reports and read the relevent sections, far from being hushed up, climatologists talk about this a ***lot***.

Now of course the greenhouse effect is self-limiting, for a start for that not to be the case we would require the Sun's luminosity to be infinite (as CO2 affects the Earth's radiative balance, but ultimately the energy comes from the sun), or equivalently to allow an infinite timescale (which isn't possible [either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution)).  The [Stefan-Boltzman law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) that says the power radiated per unit area rises with the fourth power of temperature is also a strongly limiting factor (but that doesn't rule out temperatures being very high due to the greenhouse effect, e.g. Venus, so that isn't much consolation ;o).

In short, a logarithmic relationship does not rule out a 2°C rise in global mean surface temperatures, double atmospheric CO2 concentrations a sufficient number of times and it will happen (once the radiative balance is restored, which doesn't happen immediately).  How many doublings this requires depends on the equilibrium climate sensitivity, and according to current scientific understanding (as articulated by the IPCC AR5 WG1 report) the answer is most likely one doubling (as the most probable value is a little over 2°C per doubling), but it could be less but it is very unlikely that the number is two or more doublings (as ECS below 1°C has been essentially ruled out).

Answer (score 85):

Yes it is logarithmic (although relative to amount of CO<sub>2</sub> in a sample volume of gas, not its concentration).  No that doesn't invalidate climate change.  If you want to read a detailed explanation for both answers, please see [Skeptical Science - Is the CO<sub>2</sub> effect saturated?](https://www.skepticalscience.com/saturated-CO2-effect.htm).

> The mistaken idea that the Greenhouse Effect is 'saturated', that adding more CO<sub>2</sub> will have virtually no effect, is based on a simple misunderstanding of how the Greenhouse Effect works.

This is a summary, but I leave out some details due to space constraints (and this post is already pretty long).

It is true that the effect of CO<sub>2</sub> is logarithmically related to the number of atoms of CO<sub>2</sub> in a given volume of gas.  However, this misses the critical fact that the amount of CO<sub>2</sub> varies with altitude due to changes in air pressure.  A given volume of gas at low pressure will have fewer CO<sub>2</sub> atoms in it than an equal volume of gas at a higher pressure, even if the concentration is the same.  The end result of that fact is that what directly causes the globe to warm isn't the increase in CO<sub>2</sub> levels at the ground, but rather the increase in CO<sub>2</sub> levels in the upper atmosphere, where the CO<sub>2</sub> levels are much lower and thus small changes have a much larger effect.

More specifically, what really causes global warming is an increase in the altitude at which the energy is radiated into space.  Energy arrives at Earth from the sun, where it is absorbed by the land and air.  This causes them both to heat up.  Warmer materials radiate energy, which heads back out to space.  Some of that is absorbed again by the air, which then heats up further, radiating more energy.  This continues until you reach the top levels of the atmosphere, where there is so little gas to do any absorbing the energy radiated towards space escapes into space.  CO<sub>2</sub> increases the amount of energy absorbed by the atmosphere, but does not change the amount radiated.

The amount of energy radiated is inversely related to the altitude at which it is radiated.  This is because higher altitudes are colder, and colder air radiates less energy.  So the higher the altitude where the energy escapes into space, the less total energy is released, and the more total energy is trapped, increasing temperatures.  The altitude that determines the amount of energy lost is called the [effective radiating level](http://www.aos.wisc.edu/~aos121br/radn/radn/sld012.htm) (or some variant of "effective (radiation|radiative|emission) (level|height|altitude)").

Increasing CO<sub>2</sub> levels raises the effective radiating level.  This is because more energy is being absorbed at a given altitude, and thus the higher you need to go before the energy can escape.  And since those higher altitudes are colder, less energy escapes, warming the planet.  And at those high altitudes, not only is CO<sub>2</sub> not saturated, it is at low levels where small changes are particularly significant.

This isn't just a guess, there are specific things you would expect to see if this happens.  One key one is stratospheric cooling.  Because less energy is being radiated into space, the highest levels of the atmosphere are also receiving less radiation (because that energy is being trapped at lower levels, as I explained in the previous paragraph).  So we would expect those levels of the atmosphere to be cooling while lower levels warm.  That is exactly [what we see](http://www.realclimate.org/index.php/archives/2004/12/why-does-the-stratosphere-cool-when-the-troposphere-warms/).

Further, we can use satellites to directly measure the outgoing radiation to see if it matches what we would expect from CO<sub>2</sub> blocking energy from escaping.  All molecules have a particular pattern of how much light they absorb at a given frequency, their [absorption spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectroscopy).  If CO<sub>2</sub> is really preventing energy from escaping, this should show up as a decreased in energy escaping that matches CO<sub>2</sub>'s absorption spectrum (because CO<sub>2</sub> is blocking that energy).  This [has been checked](https://www.eumetsat.int/cs/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&dDocName=pdf_conf_p50_s9_01_harries_v&allowInterrupt=1&noSaveAs=1&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased), and it is exactly what we expect from CO<sub>2</sub>-caused warming.

Comment: Everything you say is true, but it is also irrelevant to the actual question. Whatever the detail of where in the atmosphere carbon dioxide absorbs, *the absorption is still logarithmic with concentration*.

Comment: The question isn't just whether it is logarithmic, the question is whether that fact "invalidates climate change claims".  As I explain, it doesn't.

Comment: In what sense is the effect "logarithmic relative to amount, not concentration"?  If you are saying it is logarithmic relative to the amount of CO2 emissions, then that is wrong.  If you are saying it is logarithmic relative to the amount of CO2 in the atmosphere, then that is same thing as being logarithmic relative to the concentration of CO2 in the atmosphere

Comment: @Henry: It is logarithmic with respect to the amount of CO2 (number of atoms) in a sample of gas.  A lower-pressure sample of gas will have fewer CO2 atoms than a higher-pressure sample of gas with the same CO2 concentration.  I will try to clarify in my answer.

Comment: Your first link is broken, but I found the article you refer to.  I had read it already when I posted this question; I didn't find it compelling.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Link is fixed, someone did a find-replace edit on my post and messed up the link by accident.  As for the link, I provided a direct explanation for my answer in my post.  If you have any specific problems with what I said, please point it out.  "I didn't find it compelling" isn't specific enough for me to address.

Comment: The article you linked appears to address a different question.  It never mentions the logarithmic nature of CO2 warming, and the idea of "saturation" was never proposed in the original article.  It appears to be a straw man, in other words.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: They don't use the word "logarithmic" because they are trying to make it easily understood, but the principle is the same.  But I didn't write that, if you want to discuss what I wrote I would be happy to do so.

Comment: You could also just point to the Venus...

Comment: @matt_black Absorbance is linear with respect to concentration.  Transmittance decreases exponentially.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Not really. That's simplifying the problem even more than most people already do, and utterly strawman. Few people dispute that the high surface temperatures of Venus are mostly caused by the greenhouse effect. But the atmospheric pressure on Venus is 92 times that on Earth, and almost all of it is CO2. There's barely any CO2 in Earth's atmosphere; most of the warming effect is from water vapour, which is a much stronger greenhouse gas (though already saturated). I'm not saying that rising levels of CO2 are not a concern, just that your argument isn't helping at all :)

Comment: @Luaan it may not be helpful to _always just point to Venus_ to argue that CO₂ greenhouse effect is something we might want to worry about, however the conditions on Venus certainly _are_ evidence that the statement “beyond 1000+ ppmv the effect of increasing levels of CO₂ can only ever be absolutely minimal even if CO₂ concentrations were to increase indefinitely” is bunk.

Comment: @matt_black yes, which is why climate sensitivity is measured in terms of the amount of warming as a function of a ***doubling*** of atmospheric CO2, and the mainstream understanding of climate (as articulated by the IPCC) is about 1.5-4.5C per doubling, a range that has hardly change since Arrhenius.  So your point is what, exactly?

Comment: "absorption is logarithmic with temperature", but that is meaningless because what matters is not the fate of IR emitted from the surface, but the temperature of the effective layer from what IR is ***not absorbed***.  The rise in temperature is logarithmic in the CO2 concentration, but it is not as simple as being because "the absorption is still logarithmic with concentration", for the reasons The BlackCat explains.  Your understanding of the greenhouse effect is about a century out of date.

Comment: @Luaan If someone tells you that CO2 *cannot ever* warm the planet more than 2 degrees - no matter how much CO@ goes into the air, pointing to a planet where CO2 caused much more than 2 degrees temperature change is a direct refutation of the claim, not a strawman.

Comment: "A given volume of gas at low pressure will have fewer CO2 atoms in it than an equal volume of gas at a higher pressure, even if the concentration is the same." How can this possibly be true? The number of atoms is the integral of the concentration over the volume. If the concentrations are the same and the volumes are the same, the integral is trivially the same. Your statement looks false by definition. Are you sure you worded this correctly? Are you sure you're not referring to some other quantity, like the cumulative kinetic energy of the CO2 atoms (which would be different)?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial The point is merely to get a good explanation of what the physics is and why it is/isn't relevant to forecasts. Just because climate deniers might abuse a fact doesn't mean it shouldn't be explained properly.

Comment: @matt_black this answer does explain the physics, and explains them rather well, the "absorption is still logarithmic with concentration" is technically true, but entirely misleading, becase (as this answer points out), it is the temperature of the effective height from which IR is NOT absorbed that matters.

Comment: @Bridgeburners: It seems that this answer is using "concentration" to mean "volume concentration" (volume of CO₂ per volume of air) rather than "molar concentration" (amount of CO₂ per volume of air). But my reaction was the same as yours; I think that sentence would benefit from rewording.

Comment: @ruakh If I understand the definitions correctly, ppmv and ppm are proportional, and can be mutually inferred through a conversion constant. The "volume" of gas in the numerator refers to the volume that would be occupied by that gas in *ideal* temperature and pressure. If we call those T0 and P0, and the "ideal" volume Vi, then the ideal gas law states Vi = N k T0/P0 (where k is Boltzmann's constant). In the RHS, N is the only non-constant, thus "ideal volume" is simply N expressed in different units.

Answer (score 35):

No, it is not true that it invalidates climate change claims, or the need to limit further increases in CO<sub>2</sub> concentration specifically as it relates to warming (we can ignore stuff like ocean acidification for this question to keep from wandering too far abroad).  First of all, let's look at the source.  Is the person an objective scientist, making claims and analysis from professional expertise, or from actual research?  No.

The source cited in the question is a professional, paid climate science denier.  He's best known for creating and hyping faux controversies by misstating facts relating to emails between climatologists and for publishing scientifically invalid misinterpretations of NOAA data.  He is paid by the Heartland Institute, which is a phony industry "think tank" paid for by industrial polluters.  In this case he appears to be doing the same type of spin on IPCC findings.

[SourceWatch: Anthony Watts](http://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php/Anthony_Watts)

But being a paid shill does not, in and of itself, mean he's wrong.  Having a history of getting the science wrong does not mean, in and of itself, that he's getting it wrong here.  It would lead one to be less likely to give the benefit of the doubt, but if he's wrong, there should be a relatively straightforward explanation of why and how he is wrong.

Here's an explanation of what's wrong with the article that Watts is citing and quoting:

[Ed Hoskins' pseudo-science claptrap brings out all the nutters at WUWT](http://blog.hotwhopper.com/2014/08/ed-hoskins-pseudo-science-claptrap.html)

> Before going any further, it will pay to go back to the logarithmic relationship between atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> and global surface temperature. In short, what it means is that for every doubling of atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub>, the surface temperature will rise by the same fixed amount, between 1.5°C and 4.5°C, probably by around 3°C over the medium term (centuries). Many deniers think it means that for every doubling of CO<sub>2</sub>, temperature will rise much less, but that's wrong. It will go up by roughly the same amount when CO<sub>2</sub> doubles (at foreseeable levels). The typical science denier doesn't do maths.
>
> Ed's article is all over the place like a dog's breakfast, **but his main very wrong message is that CO<sub>2</sub> can rise to 1000 ppm without any bad consequences. That's just not so.**
>
> Ed's argument is that because the effect of CO<sub>2</sub> on temperature is logarithmic, it will only have a tiny impact as it increases. The first part is true. The relationship is logarithmic. However the second part is relative. What might seem a "tiny impact" for, say, a diurnal temperature variation would have an enormous impact if it were an increase in average surface temperature over the entire world. From our perspective, the impact on climate and ocean acidification and rising sea levels will be hugely damaging as more and more CO<sub>2</sub> is emitted.
>
> A rise in atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> from pre-industrial times (say 280 ppm) to 1000 ppm would mean an increase of 3.5 times. That would mean a rise in global surface temperature of somewhere between around 2.8°C and 8°C degrees or more.
>
> According to an analysis by Steven C. Sherwood and Matthew Huber, a rise of 7°C in average surface temperature would result in a wet bulb temperature of more than 35°C in much of the world, which would stretch our physiological limits beyond tolerance. We wouldn't be able to maintain our core body temperature and would overheat. People die from heat stroke every year as it is, without a wet bulb temperature of 35°C. We cannot survive temperatures above a certain level and humidity. We can't sweat it out.
>
> I wondered how Ed Hoskins came up with his magical thinking. He went back to the third assessment report of the IPCC for some reason, back thirteen years to 2001.  He wrote:
>
> *quotes the same passages as the OP here*
>
> He thinks that something "is well disguised".  Well, it looks as if it is so "well-disguised" that Ed himself cannot understand it. Thing is, it doesn't "radically diminish". **He wrote about the IPCC publishing views about the effect of CO<sub>2</sub> up to 1000 ppm, but doesn't show it. Instead he shows charts from denier Steve Milloy** who admits that what he writes is junk science. (That's the name of his blog.)
>
> So does the IPCC publish views about the effect of CO<sub>2</sub> up to 1000 ppm?  There were only four mentions of the words "1000 ppm" in the latest IPCC report, and three of them referred to the same period in Earth's history, the Early Eocene Climatic Optimum. (The other was a reference to stomata.) Here are two of them:
>
> During the Early Eocene (52 to 48 million years ago), atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> concentration exceeded ~1000 ppm when global mean surface temperature was 9°C to 14°C higher (medium confidence) than for pre-industrial conditions. [IPCC AR5 WG1:TS.2.8 Changes in Carbon and Other Biogeochemical Cycles]
>   The EECO [Early Eocence Climatic Optimum] represents the last time atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> concentrations may have reached a level of ~1000 ppm (Section 5.2.2.2). There were no substantial polar ice sheets, and oceanic and continental configurations, vegetation type and distribution were significantly different from today. Whereas simulated SAT are in reasonable agreement with reconstructions (Huber and Caballero, 2011; Lunt et al., 2012) (Box 5.1, Figure 1d), there are still significant discrepancies between simulated and reconstructed mean annual SST, which are reduced if seasonal biases in some of the marine proxies are considered for the high-latitude sites (Hollis et al., 2012; Lunt et al., 2012). Medium confidence is placed on the reconstructed global mean surface temperature anomaly estimate of 8°C–14°C. [IPCC AR5 WG1: 5.3.1 High CO<sub>2</sub> Worlds and Temperature]
>
> **In other words, the last time when the atmospheric concentration was 1000 ppm or more was 52 to 48 million years ago and the global mean surface temperature was 9°C to 14°C higher than it was in pre-industrial times in this modern era.** Does that seem like a tiny effect to you? Does it strike you as inconsequential that vast areas of land would become uninhabitable because the wet bulb temperature would be intolerable for humans?

In a nutshell, being logarithmic doesn't magically cap the upper bound.  If we more than double the atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> (currently around 400 ppm) to 1000 ppm, we will see more than the amount of warming stated in the question.  And that ignores a lot of other factors, as well, but since the basic concept is wrong, we don't need to delve into that.

Comment: You should probably explain why we should trust HotWhopper since not every statement in that quote cites another source.

Comment: @called2voyage - Did you go to the actual linked article? It's packed with hyperlinks as well as references to original documents.  (for instance "there were only four mentions of the word '1000 ppm' in the latest IPCC report" includes the "IPCC report" as a hyperlink.)  If you're not aware of that, then I'd say your mistaken in claiming this author doesn't include references.

Comment: I'm not talking about the author, but your post. You should include those references in your own post, just in case the blog goes down.

Comment: @called2voyage - Okay, so I need to link the links in my links?  Do I also need to link the citations and links in the links that my link linked?  Nonsense.  You were claiming the citations did not exist (questioning the credibility of the source due to lack thereof), which means you didn't bother looking.  If you didn't bother looking at what I did link, why would adding more links that you wouldn't bother looking at make any difference?

Comment: Actually I did read the entire article. I was just saying that you didn't include any of the citations in the quote.

Comment: @called2voyage - "not every statement in that quote cites..." you absolutely are referencing that author.  The original question links to an article that is quoting another source, that, probably includes references to yet other sources.  I don't see you complaining that we're not three levels deep in sourcing for the original question, which only links the original article.  That's a pretty arbitrary standard.  If you read the source and see that the links are there, why is it phrased as "you need to explain why we should trust....?"  Your later statements don't map to the original comment.

Comment: Yes, the portion you quoted did not include any but the ipcc cite. HotWhopper is not notable so you need to show their sources.

Comment: I never said to go three levels deep. Answers have a higher standard than questions. Stop arguing about what you think I meant. You can either take the criticism or not. For what it's worth I like your post, I was just trying to help improve it.

Comment: HotWhopper includes her sourcing and links, that are available via the link already provided.  Again, "what if the link goes down" applies to any additional links you are asking for.  The standard is that you provide references.  She does mention where she gets all of her material from, so it's not like she's stating something that looks like opinion, with links buried.  She states that it's the IPCC report. She states that analysis is from specific authors, by name, along with the links.  It's there, if the links go down.

Comment: @called2voyage - There's nothing hidden in the quote.  What your asking for seems, as I said, arbitrary and tedious and a standard which would lead to never-ending links of links of links of links.  It's there, in the link, and it's mentioned, specifically, by name, if for some reason that link should die.

Comment: "The source cited in the question is a professional, paid climate science denier".  That needs to be backed up or deleted.

Comment: I go one step further than Monty and think your should just remove everything related to criticizing the "science denier" even if you prove he's paid. There is absolutely no source that doesn't have their own agenda. NONE, ZERO, NADA. So the same claim can be made in every single post no matter what position one takes and it adds no value. Also, once someone starts their answer with something like that, all I read afterwards is yada, yada, yada. Knocking down the "science denier's" arguments one at a time is great, but attacking motivations causes your message to be lost.

Comment: That's nonsense. Having an agenda to expand the understanding and knowledge in a scientific field is not an agenda that creates a conflict of interest nor does it create a situation where one might misrepresent.  Being a paid propagandist is not the same, at all, so the claim that "everyone does it" is nonsense, and the motivations of people denying actual science and having a track record of making claims that have been disproven is absolutely relevant.

Answer (score 10):

The first part of the claim is:

> the effectiveness of CO2 as a greenhouse gas diminishes logarithmically with increasing concentration and from the current level of ~390 ppmv, (parts per million by volume). Accordingly only ~5% of the effectiveness of CO2 as a greenhouse gas remains beyond the current level.

Expressions using logarithmic functions have been published for [radiative forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_forcing) and temperature.

For example in [New Estimates of Radiative Forcing due to well Mixed Greenhouse Gases](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/98GL01908/abstract) there is the **approximate** expression:

ΔF = 5.35ln(C/C<sub>0</sub>)

where "ΔF" is change in radiative forcing and "C" is CO2 concentration.

However, contrary to the claim, a [logarithmic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), such as ln(C), approaches infinity as C approaches infinity. There is no limit to the amount of forcing as C increases.

Secondly, it is immediately obvious that the above equation is just an approximation valid in a limited range, ln(C) approaches negative infinity as C approaches 0, ridiculously predicting zero CO2 concentration results in an infinitely negative amount of forcing.

A more detailed formula is available from [Model Forcasts of Global Climate Changes](https://pubs.giss.nasa.gov/docs/1988/1988_Hansen_ha02700w.pdf) at page 9360:

> ΔT = f(C) - f(C<sub>0</sub>)
>
> f(x) = ln(1 + 1.2x + 0.005x<sup>2</sup> + 0.0000014x<sup>3</sup>)
>
> C<sub>0</sub> = 315ppmv

where ΔT is change in temperature

The above formula is said to be valid up to 1000 ppmv, where upon a 2 °C increase relative to 1958 has already been exceeded.  This model does not consider feedback mechanisms.

Comment: Aside from the adjustment in terminology, does the claim still hold true?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, because it's ignoring the thermodynamics that result from transmittance going to zero. The earth loses heat to space by radiation, because space has no air for convection. If the atmosphere is completely opaque to long wavelengths, then the earth heats up until it can transmit shorter wavelengths. Thermal equilibrium moves to a higher temperature. The last little bit of transmittance is critical, but the article in question is making contortions to minimize its significance.

Comment: Your whole answer seems to be based on the reasoning that `f(C)` is unbounded for infinite values of `C`. But how exactly can concentration approach infinity when it can't be more than 100% by definition?

Comment: As Dmitry points out, this answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The more detailed model equation is only stated to be valid up to the 1000 ppmv range, and the less detailed one would be even worse.  CO2 concentration (in principle) can exceed what would now be 100% on Earth, for example like on Venus were pressure is 90 times that of Earth.

Comment: This answer isn't wrong.  As GEP Box said, "all models are wrong, but some are useful".  The logarithmic relationship discussed here is a simplified model of the true relationship, and being a simplification is "wrong" by definition.  It is still perfectly useful for the purposes of this question because for sensible values of climate sensitivity we are going to reach the 2°C figure well before either approximation becomes invalid.  Quibbling about infinite atmospheric CO2 is missing the point, especially since the other infinite case was explicitly mentioned! +1 @DavePhD

Comment: FWIW the second formula seems to suggest 946ppm is required for a rise of 2°C, but perhaps that is a "no-feedback" sensitivity?  946ppm is a fair bit less than infinity.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial yes, it predicts 946ppm to rise 2 degrees from the 1958 situation.  This is based on a 1981 model of Lacis et al. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/GL008i010p01035/abstract So it is an old model, but sensible enough to make the equation not go to negative infinite with zero CO2 concentration.  Yes, it is for infinite time (equilibrium) but no feedback.

Comment: @DavePhD yes, I thought the figure looked a bit high, but with feedback mechanisms as well, I suspect the true ECS implied would be well within the current IPCC AR5 WG1 bracket, so about 600ppm would probably be more than sufficient (which is even less than infinity ;o)